# Display Wordpress Category

Tags: wordpress

I want to display only the those parent category name and with their child category..

Example category 
`AAAAA,BBBB,CCCCC,DDDDD`
Parent category `AAAAA` having child category `a,b,c` 
Parent category `BBBB` having child category `x,y,z`

Now I want to display only (Result required)

```
AAAAA    
    a,b,c 
BBBB    
    x,y,z
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If CCCCC's id is 17 and DDDDD id is 38, then the following example would work.

```
   <ul>
      <?php wp_list_pages('exclude=17,38' ); ?>
    </ul>
```